# Running a .bat through a .vbs

Tags: batch-file, vbscript

I am trying to make a pretty simple .vbs in Notepad that will do the following, but I am having a bit of trouble as I am a little new to scripting:

- Execute a .bat if you select 'Yes', and close the window and do nothing if you select 'No'.
- Display a message so you know why you're hitting 'Yes' or 'No'.
- Display a window title.

Here's what I have tried to make myself so far:

```
x=msgbox("MESSAGE HERE",4,"WINDOW TITLE HERE")
const Hidden = 0
const WaitOnReturn = true
set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.Run "%HOMEPATH%\Documents\FOLDER\FOLDER\EXAMPLE.BAT", Hidden, WaitOnReturn
WScript.Echo "Done"
```

It works just fine, however, even if I select 'No', it will still execute the .bat, which I do not want.

Comment: so add an `if` to test what the user entered.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply, Marc!

Would you mind elaborating on how I'd integrate that into my current script? Or if I could do it better/easier?

Regards,

Patrick

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5h27x7e9%28v=vs.84%29.aspx

Comment: Please do not include text like "Thanks", "Any help appreciated", or signatures in your posts. You can thank those that provide helpful answers by upvoting or accepting their answers, and every question, answer or comment you post here has your identity in the lower right corner so we know who you are already. :-) There's more info if you need it in the [help/behavior] - see "Do not use signature, taglines, or greetings".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code :

```
Option Explicit
Const Hidden = 0
Const WaitOnReturn = True
Dim Question,BatchFilePath,Message,Title,Result
Title = "Running a .bat through a .vbs"
Message = "Did you want to continue executing this script"
BatchFilePath = "%ProgramFiles%\FolderTest\Folder Name with spaces\EXAMPLE.BAT"
'We add the double quotes in this variable to bypass spaces issues in the path
BatchFilePath = DblQuote(BatchFilePath)
Question = Msgbox(Message,VbYesNo + VbQuestion,Title)
If Question = VbNo Then
    MsgBox "You have chosen to quit this script !",vbExclamation,Title
    WScript.Quit() ' We quit the script
Else
    Result = Run(BatchFilePath,Hidden,WaitOnReturn)
End If
'*********************************************************************
Function Run(StrCmd,Console,bWaitOnReturn)
    Dim ws,MyCmd,Result
    Set ws = CreateObject("wscript.Shell")
'A value of 0 to hide the MS-DOS console
    If Console = 0 Then
        MyCmd = "CMD /C " & StrCmd & ""
        Result = ws.run(MyCmd,Console,bWaitOnReturn)
        If Result = 0 Then
            MsgBox "Success",VbInformation,Title
        Else
            MsgBox "An unknown error has occurred!",16,"An unknown error has occurred!"
        End If
    End If
'A value of 1 to show the MS-DOS console
    If Console = 1 Then
        MyCmd = "CMD /K " & StrCmd & ""
        Result = ws.run(MyCmd,Console,bWaitOnReturn)
        If Result = 0 Then
            MsgBox "Success",VbInformation,Title
        Else
            MsgBox "An unknown error has occurred!",16,"An unknown error has occurred!"
        End If
    End If
    Run = Result
End Function
'*********************************************************************
Function DblQuote(Str)
    DblQuote = Chr(34) & Str & Chr(34)
End Function
'*********************************************************************
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
Set obj = CreateObject("WScript.shell")

Answer = MsgBox("Content Here",vbYesNo,"Title Here")
If Answer = vbYes Then
obj.Run "PATH TO BATCH FILE"
Else
WScript.Quit 0
End If
```